# Manually apply a commit to files in repository

Tags: git

I am trying to compile `gcc 10.3` from source. In order for it to compile on modern kernels (which don't have the `<linux/cyclades.h>` header), I need to manually apply a certain commit that removes the cyclades-related lines of code from gcc (that commit was after 10.3 release). In particular, that commit removes several lines from three files.

I have the source code of `gcc 10.3`. **I want** to automatically apply the diff of that commit to it - automatically edit the three files according to the commit. **It needs to be done automatically**. Is there a way to do so without manually using `sed` with hand-crafted calls for each line of code that was removed?

Comment: It sounds like you are simply describing [git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)? `git cherry-pick <COMMIT_HASH>` applies the specified commit to the current commit. It will be automatic, assuming there is no conflict. In case of conflicts, you will need to manually resolve the conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I want can be achieved with the `patch` command. On Fedora it can be installed with `sudo dnf install patch`. I learned how to use `patch` by reading [a post on redhat.com](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/git-diff-patch-commands).

Comment: patch is not a Git command. However, `git apply` is a similar (NOT identical!) command that *is* a Git command.